# How do I have to use gotoAndStop() here?

Tags: javascript

I'm new into html/javascript, before I only used Actionscript3. If I do it like this it tells me "gotoAndStop is not a function". And if I remove `this` it tells me "gotoAndStop is not defined". What do I need to put so I get it move to the next frame when the mouse is being moved while pressed?

```
this.stop()

this.movieClip.addEventListener("pressmove", goMove, this);

function goMove(e){
    
    var frameCount = 1
    
    if (e.stageX < 100){
        frameCount = 1
    }
    else if (e.stageX > 115 && e.stageX < 130){
        frameCount = 2
    }
    else if (e.stageX > 130 && e.stageX < 145){
        frameCount = 3
    }
    else if (e.stageX > 145 && e.stageX < 160){
        frameCount = 4
    }
    else if (e.stageX > 160 && e.stageX < 175){
        frameCount = 5
    }
    else if (e.stageX > 175 && e.stageX < 190){
        frameCount = 6
    }
    else if (e.stageX > 190 && e.stageX < 205){
        frameCount = 7
    }
    else if (e.stageX > 205 && e.stageX < 220){
        frameCount = 8
    }
    else if (e.stageX > 220 && e.stageX < 235){
        frameCount = 9
    }
    else if (e.stageX > 235 && e.stageX < 250){
        frameCount = 10
    }
    else if (e.stageX > 250 && e.stageX < 265){
        frameCount = 11
    }
    else if (e.stageX > 265 && e.stageX < 280){
        frameCount = 12
    }
    else if (e.stageX > 280 && e.stageX < 295){
        frameCount = 13
    }
    else if (e.stageX > 295 && e.stageX < 310){
        frameCount = 14
    }
    else if (e.stageX > 310 && e.stageX < 325){
        frameCount = 15
    }
    else if (e.stageX > 325 && e.stageX < 340){
        frameCount = 16
    }
    else if (e.stageX > 340 && e.stageX < 355){
        frameCount = 17
    }
    else if (e.stageX > 355 && e.stageX < 370){
        frameCount = 18
    }
    else if (e.stageX > 370 && e.stageX < 385){
        frameCount = 19
    }
    else if (e.stageX > 385 && e.stageX < 400){
        frameCount = 20
    }
    else if (e.stageX > 400 && e.stageX < 415){
        frameCount = 21
    }
    else if (e.stageX > 415 && e.stageX < 430){
        frameCount = 22
    }
    else if (e.stageX > 430 && e.stageX < 445){
        frameCount = 23
    }
    else if (e.stageX > 445 && e.stageX < 460){
        frameCount = 24
    }
    else if (e.stageX > 460 && e.stageX < 475){
        frameCount = 25
    }
    else if (e.stageX > 475 && e.stageX < 490){
        frameCount = 26
    }
    else if (e.stageX > 490 && e.stageX < 505){
        frameCount = 27
    }
    else if (e.stageX > 505 && e.stageX < 520){
        frameCount = 28
    }
    else if (e.stageX > 520 && e.stageX < 535){
        frameCount = 29
    }
    else if (e.stageX > 535 && e.stageX < 550){
        frameCount = 30
    }
    else if (e.stageX > 550 && e.stageX < 565){
        frameCount = 31
    }
    else if (e.stageX > 565 && e.stageX < 580){
        frameCount = 32
    }
    else if (e.stageX > 580 && e.stageX < 595){
        frameCount = 33
    }
    else if (e.stageX > 595 && e.stageX < 610){
        frameCount = 34
    }
    else if (e.stageX > 610 && e.stageX < 625){
        frameCount = 35
    }
    else if (e.stageX > 625 && e.stageX < 640){
        frameCount = 36
    }
    else if (e.stageX > 640 && e.stageX < 655){
        frameCount = 37
    }
    else if (e.stageX > 655 && e.stageX < 670){
        frameCount = 38
    }
    else if (e.stageX > 670 && e.stageX < 685){
        frameCount = 39
    }
    else if (e.stageX > 685){
        frameCount = 40
    }
    
    switch(frameCount){
        case 1: this.gotoAndStop(1)
            break
        
        case 2: this.gotoAndStop(2)
            break
        
        case 3: this.gotoAndStop(3)
            break
        
        case 4: this.gotoAndStop(4)
            break
        
        case 5: this.gotoAndStop(5)
            break
        
        case 6: this.gotoAndStop(6)
            break
        
        case 7: this.gotoAndStop(7)
            break
        
        case 8: this.gotoAndStop(8)
            break
        
        case 9: this.gotoAndStop(9)
            break
        
        case 10: this.gotoAndStop(10)
            break
        
        case 11: this.gotoAndStop(11)
            break
        
        case 12: this.gotoAndStop(12)
            break
        
        case 13: this.gotoAndStop(13)
            break
        
        case 14: this.gotoAndStop(14)
            break
        
        case 15: this.gotoAndStop(15)
            break
        
        case 16: this.gotoAndStop(16)
            break
        
        case 17: this.gotoAndStop(17)
            break
        
        case 18: this.gotoAndStop(18)
            break
        
        case 19: this.gotoAndStop(19)
            break
        
        case 20: this.gotoAndStop(20)
            break
        
        case 21: this.gotoAndStop(21)
            break
        
        case 22: this.gotoAndStop(22)
            break
        
        case 23: this.gotoAndStop(23)
            break
        
        case 24: this.gotoAndStop(24)
            break
        
        case 25: this.gotoAndStop(25)
            break
        
        case 26: this.gotoAndStop(26)
            break
        
        case 27: this.gotoAndStop(27)
            break
        
        case 28: this.gotoAndStop(28)
            break
        
        case 29: this.gotoAndStop(29)
            break
        
        case 30: this.gotoAndStop(30)
            break
        
        case 31: this.gotoAndStop(31)
            break
        
        case 32: this.gotoAndStop(32)
            break
        
        case 33: this.gotoAndStop(33)
            break
        
        case 34: this.gotoAndStop(34)
            break
        
        case 35: this.gotoAndStop(35)
            break
        
        case 36: this.gotoAndStop(36)
            break
        
        case 37: this.gotoAndStop(37)
            break
        
        case 38: this.gotoAndStop(38)
            break
        
        case 39: this.gotoAndStop(39)
            break
        
        case 40: this.gotoAndStop(40)
            break
        
    }
}
```

Comment: by using `this` you try execute `gotoAndStop` method from `goMove` function context. Check the scope where your declared `gotoAndStop` method.

Comment: WTH? Why don't you just call `this.gotoAndStop(frameCount)` instead of that `switch` statement? Similarly, that `if` cascade should be just `const frameCount = Math.max(1, Math.min(40, Math.floor((e.stageX - 100) / 15)))`